# Torah atones for all sins

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study, talmud-gemara, sin

I once read a quote that said, *"Learning Torah atones for all sins."*

Does anyone know where this Men*achos, Kesubos* or *Eruvin*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this source: [מדרש תנאים לספר דברים Medrash Tanoim to Sefer Devorim](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_33216_191.pdf)

ד״א יערף כמ׳ לק׳ ר׳ יוסי הגלילי אומ׳ אין עריפה אלא לשון כפרה שנ׳ (כא ד) וערפו שם את העגלה בנחל מה עגלה מכפרת על שפיכות דמים **כך תורה מכפרת על כל עבירות**:

Comment: Does that mean **learning** Torah? Maybe it means fulfilling the Torah's dictates.

Answer (score 4):

One source in the Talmud Bavli<sup>1</sup> that makes a similar statement is [*B'rachos* 5a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=5&format=text)-[b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=5b&format=text):

> תני תנא קמיה דר' יוחנן כל העוסק בתורה ובגמילות חסדים וקובר את בניו מוחלין לו על כל עונותיו אמר ליה רבי יוחנן בשלמא תורה וגמילות חסדים דכתיב בחסד ואמת יכופר עון... אמת זו תורה שנאמר אמת קנה ואל תמכור

Translation:

> A teacher of Tannaitic teachings taught in the presence of R' Yochanan: "All who engage in Torah study, engage in acts of kindness, or are predeceased by their children are pardoned for all of their sins." Rabbi Yochanan said to him: "...'Through kindness and truth, sin is atoned' ([*Mishlei* 16:6](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2816.htm#6))... 'Truth' refers to Torah, as it says, 'Acquire truth, and do not sell it' ([*Mishlei* 23:23](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2823.htm#23))...."

---

<sup>1</sup> 
<sub>Another somewhat relevant source is [*Rosh HaShana* 18a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=9&daf=18&format=text):</sub>

> <sub>Rav Sh'mu'el bar Ami (and there are those who say Rav Sh'mu'el Bar Nachmani) said in the name of Rav Yonasan: "From where do we know that a divine decree accompanied by an oath cannot be rescinded?..." Rava [or possibly Rabba] said, "It cannot be atoned via sacrifices and *mincha* offerings, but it can be atoned via Torah." Abaye said, "It cannot be atoned via sacrifices and *mincha* offerings, but it can be atoned via Torah and kind deeds."</sub>

<sub>If you are specifically looking for a source from one of the tractates that you mentioned, [*K'subos* 111b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=15&daf=111b&format=text) is vaguely relevant ("Rabbi Elazar said, 'Anyone who avails himself of the light of Torah, the light of Torah brings him supernal life....'"):</sub>

> <sub>אמר ר' אלעזר... כל המשתמש באור תורה אור תורה מחייהו וכל שאין משתמש באור תורה אין אור תורה מחייהו כיון דחזייה דקמצטער א"ל רבי מצאתי להן תקנה מן התורה ואתם הדבקים בה' אלהיכם חיים כולכם היום וכי אפשר לדבוקי בשכינה והכתיב כי ה' אלהיך אש אוכלה אלא כל המשיא בתו לתלמיד חכם והעושה פרקמטיא לתלמידי חכמים והמהנה תלמידי חכמים מנכסיו מעלה עליו הכתוב כאילו מדבק בשכינה כיוצא בדבר אתה אומר לאהבה את ה' אלהיך ולדבקה בו וכי אפשר לאדם לידבק בשכינה אלא כל המשיא בתו לתלמיד חכם והעושה פרקמטיא לתלמידי חכמים והמהנה תלמידי חכמים מנכסיו מעלה עליו הכתוב כאילו מדבק בשכינה</sub>

<sub>So is [*M'nachos* 110a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=30&daf=110&format=text) ("Reish Lakish said, '...Anyone who is involved in Torah, it is as if he offered *olah*, *mincha*, *chatas*, and *asham* offerings.'... Rava said, 'Anyone who is involved in Torah requires neither *olah*, nor *mincha*, (nor *chatas*,) nor *asham* offerings.'"):</sub>

> <sub>אמר ריש לקיש מאי דכתיב זאת התורה לעולה למנחה ולחטאת ולאשם כל העוסק בתורה כאילו הקריב עולה מנחה חטאת ואשם אמר רבא האי לעולה למנחה עולה ומנחה מיבעי ליה אלא אמר רבא כל העוסק בתורה אינו צריך לא עולה (ולא חטאת) ולא מנחה ולא אשם</sub>

Comment: Do you have specific basis for translating "וקובר" as "or..." rather than "and..." or is it just what you think seems most sensible from the context?

Comment: @msh210 I translated it as "or" because the subsequent discussion in the gemara seems to treat each of these separately.

Answer (score 2):

The Pele Yoetz writes:

חידוש

> - [[ידוע]] מעלת המחדש חדושי תורה שהוא חשוב מאד בשמים ממעל עד שאמרו בזהר הקדוש (בהקדמה ז)) ד) שבונה שמים חדשים ועליו הכתוב אומר (ישעיה נא
>     טז) לנטע שמים וליסד ארץ ולאמר לציון שערים המצינים בהלכה עמי אתה. אל
>     תקרי עמי, אלא עמי (שם דף ה), שנעשה שתף להקדוש ברוך הוא. וכל אדם אינו
>     חיב אלא כשעורו, רק שיעמל בכל כחו לחדש חדושי תורה, דהינו להקשות ולתרץ
>     בתנ''ך ובש''ס או לפרש פרושים בפרד''ס (פשט, רמז, דרוש, סוד) על תנ''ך
>     וש''ס, והוא תקון גדול לכל עון ולכל חטאת ובפרט לעון פגם הברית, שהזרע
>     יוצא מן המח ותקונו שיטרח במחו לחדש חדושי תורה ובפרט בשבת חשוב מאד
>     כשמחדש חדושי תורה, כאשר הפליג בשבחו בזהר הקדוש (ח''ג דף קעג) מה מגיע
>     אליו ומה נעשה יקר וגדלה לנפש אביו ואמו (כבר יצא עת''ק לשון הזהר הקדוש
>     בקנטרס ''אורות אילים''). ולמי שאין ידו משגת לחדש חדושי תורה מדעתו, כבר
>     יש תקנה שילמד חדושי תורה את אשר כבר עשוהו ונכתב בספר, כל אשר ילמד וידע
>     את אשר לא ידעו חשוב כאלו חדשו. ועל זאת ישתדל מאד כל היודע ספר לפחות
>     ללמד בשבת דבר חדש, ואם אינו יודע ספר ישתדל לשמע בלמודים מפי סופרים דבר
>     חדש אשר לא ידעו. וגם למוד ספר הזהר הקדוש אף באין מבין חשוב כאלו חדש
>     חדושים. ואחד המרבה ואחד הממעיט ובלבד שיכון לבו לשמים: [[וכל]] אשר יחדש
>     יכתב ידו בספר ואל יהי בז להן, וכן יכתב ידו כל אשר ישמע דבר חדש, שהרי
>     כתבו המפרשים (סכר חסידים סי' תקל) שעכשו שאין בית המק, דש קים ואין
>     קרבנות, **הכותב חדושי תורה מכפר עליו כאלו הקריב קרבנות,** ואסמכוה אקרא
>     (תהלים מ ז) עולה וחטאה לא שאלת אז אמרתי הנה באתי במגלת ספר כתוב עלי.
>     וכתבו גם כן שעתיד אדם לתן את הדין על שגלו לו חדושי תורה ולא כתבם, שלא
>     גלו לו אלא על מנת שיכתבם ויהנו ממנו ולמטי לה הנאה שיהיו שפתותיו דובבות
>     בקבר. ומי יתן והיה שיכתב אדם כל אשר שומע חדושי תורה מילדותו והיה יכול
>     לעשות טוב מדברים מתוקים מדבש ונחמדים מזהב, ואף שיש דברים שכבר המה
>     בכתובים, אבל יש הרבה שעדין לא נתנו לכתב, ועל כל פנים היה יותר טוב מאד
>     ללקט ביחד כל אשר ישמע דברים מתוקים וחריפים, וחסד היה עושה עם אותן שאין
>     בידם אותם ספרים וילמדו הדבר מתוך ספרו ומנה ומניהו יתקלס עלאה:
>     [[וכאשר]] גדלה מעלת הלומד חדושי תורה כל קבל דנא רע ירוע למי שאוהב לשמע
>     חדושי והבלי העולם הזה, רעתו רבה שמתוך כך מרבה בבטול תורה, בכל צואה
>     יתגלע והן הם מערבבים את מחו בשעת התפלה וכל עבודתו פסולה. ולו בכח יגבר
>     איש אשר גבר עליו יצרו והרגל בכך להיות אוהב לשמע חדושים, יחיש מפלט לו
>     וידחק את עצמו לשנא את החדושים שאינם צריכים לו לצרך פרנסתו באמר, מה יתן
>     ומה יוסיף לי ידיעת הבלי העולם, ההעדר טוב ממציאות הרע. וכבר אמרו
>     רבותינו ז''ל (כתובות ה, ב) אל ישמיע אדם לאזניו דברים בטלים שהם נכוות
>     תחלה לאיברים. ולכל דבר טוב שלא הרגל בו ולמשך ידו מעשות כל רע שהרגל בו
>     צריך חזוק ושיעשה מלחמה עם היצר הרע בתחבולות וזה כאחד מהם יתחזק לעשות
>     חיל ויהפך רע בטוב וה' יתן הטוב:

Answer (score 2):

Tshuvas Maharit #100 discusses a a certain chacham who would darshan in the name of the Zohar 'מאן דאשתדל באורייתא לא מתבעי מיניה דינא כלל', 'whosoever learns Torah, will not be judged at all'.

He spends the entire tshuva bringing chazzal proving this is not true. We find the mishna saying learning is not the focus, mitzvos are. There were great tzadikim who died because they were only involved with Torah and not gemilas chessed. The gemara says all Hashem is concerned with in this world is our fear of heaven.

The only Chazzal which may have implied this was the gemara in Chagiga which compares a Talmid Chacham to a salamandera (the mythical creature) who is not harmed by fire, so too a Talmid Chacham is not affected by the fire of Gehinom. But he says all the Chazzal showed how Hashem is even more exacting on those close to him mean we can't take these words at face value. Instead he suggests the intention is just like the salamandera is not harmed all the while it's in the fire, so too the Talmid Chacham as long as he stays in the beis midrash learning, he won't go sin and therefore won't be subject to the fires of Gehinom.

He ends off by saying someone brought him the Zohar and the intent there was entirely different than how it was quoted. What the Zohar meant was as long as someone learns Torah, no sin will come to his hand, for the Torah saves as so long as one is involved with it. He proves this with the fact that the Zohar brings the drasha of 'charus al haluchos' cheirus, freedom from the yetzer hara, freedom from the malach hamaves (shmos rabba 41 7).

This is the two step process, not a get out of jail free card.

Comment: +1 If we're venturing into the Zohar, the Zohar on *Sh'lach* ([159a](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%96%D7%94%D7%A8_%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7_%D7%92_%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%98_%D7%90)) is a direct source that all of one's sins are pardoned as a result toiling in Torah study (see the first footnote in the *Sha'ar HaTorah* of *Sh'miras HaLashon*, which mentions the caveat that one must make things right with people he wronged): "רבי יהודה פתח... דכל מאן דאשתדל באורייתא כאילו מקריב כל קורבנין דעלמא לקמי קב"ה ולא עוד אלא דקב"ה מכפר ליה על כל חובוי ומתקנין ליה כמה כורסיין לעלמא דאתי".

Comment: @Fred Hhmm this one would be harder (impossible?) for the Rivash to darshan away. Were you being maavir sidra with Zohar when you found this?:)

Comment: There might be some way to reconcile this with the Maharit (does the Rivash say this, too?), for e.g. by saying that Torah brings a measure of atonement for any sins committed but does not forestall judgment entirely for sins committed. | I found it in *Sh'miras HaLashon* ([*Sha'ar HaTorah*, ch. 2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47571&st=&pgnum=190)).

Comment: @Fred oh brother:/ No I didn't see this in Rivash. I happened to have been learning in the Rivash when I typed that. You are referring to that part he says in the name of Medrash Hane'elam? That's interesting but I don't think the Maharit (yes, I just typed Rivash again!) would entertain that thought though. A side point, is quoting the Zohar quoting a medrash hane'elam ? Does that make sense?

Comment: To your side point: Yes, that makes sense to me.

Comment: @Fred :) K. I guess it makes sense to me too. I just wasn't aware that such quotes happened.

Comment: It seems that the OP was looking for sources that confirm, rather than negate the notion.

Comment: @mevaqesh by that logic any answer would need to be sourced only from "Menachos, Kesubos or Eruvin" which is not true, proven by the accepted check next to an answer that sources from none of the above. But in a more general sense you are correct. However, sometimes proof of negation is appreciated as well to various OPs. That's why I wrote this answer.